# Adding image to datagridview image coloumn in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add image to the image column of datagridview, using the following code but it returns an error

> system.argumentexception: Parameter is not valid

```
ofdLogoImage.ShowDialog()
vrPicHolder = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ofdLogoImage.FileName)
dgvLogo.Item(3, dgvLogo.Rows.Count - 1).Value = vrPicHolder
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass Image to that cell.

You can use this code

```
ofdLogoImage.ShowDialog()
Dim vrPic = Image.FromFile(ofdLogoImage.FileName)
dgvLogo.Item(3, dgvLogo.Rows.Count - 1).Value = vrPic
```